# How to force npm install on elastic beanstalk node 16?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have issues on elastic beanstalk because of some peer dependencies. In EB logs, I can see `npm install --production` is failing.

How can I customize EB platform to either let me run install by myself (i was able to do this with Procfile on node 14 platform) or pass flags such as `--force` to the command.

I am on the latest node 16 platform (using npm 8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy way for me was to add `npm_config_force=true` to Software environment variables in EB.

Comment: How do I make this configuration?

Comment: Go to configuration in EBS and edit "Updates, monitoring, and logging" --> Scroll down to the last option "Environment properties". Then add the environment variable:
Key: npm_config_force ; Value: true